# How does one change props value to a different variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> The problem is I can't access the value of actuve
> or change it? Is this because of the fact that
> props are immutable? and if so I should I
> create a separate variable for each
> EventInLife element/component?

```js
import React from 'react';
import styled,{ css } from 'styled-components';


const EventInLife = (props) => {
    /*
    adds the active theme to each element(example: if active then the styles 
    would be barbar and barbaractive if not they would be barbar and barbar)
    */
    return (
        <div className={`barbar barbar${ props.actuve }`}>
            <div className={`square square${ props.actuve }`}></div>
            <div className={`heading  heading${ props.actuve }`}>{props.heading}</div>
            <div className={`date date${ props.actuve }`}>{props.date}</div>
        </div>
    );
}

function App() {
    //Manages which value is active
    
    var lastactive=0;
    function bruh(t,n){
        document.getElementsByName(t)[lastactive].actuve='';
        document.getElementsByName(t)[n].actuve = 'active';
        lastactive=n;
    }

    return(
        <EventInLife heading={'Top'} date={'145'} actuve={'active'} onClick={()=>bruh('EventInLife',0)}/>
        <EventInLife heading={'trop'} date={'456456'} actuve={''} onClick={()=>bruh('EventInLife',1)}/>
        <EventInLife heading={'brop'} date={'45646'} actuve={''} onClick={()=>bruh('EventInLife',2)}/>
        <EventInLife heading={'crop'} date={'45646'} actuve={''} onClick={()=>bruh('EventInLife',3)}/>
        <EventInLife heading={'wrop'} date={'145645'} actuve={''} onClick={()=>bruh('EventInLife',4)}/>
    );
}
```

```css
/*the css style names (i made them only overide what they needed to)*/
.barbar{}
.barbaractive{}
.squareactive{}
.squareactive{}
.headingactive{}
.headingactive{}
.dateactive{}
.dateactive{}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes props are immutable, think of them as arguments being passed to a function. Any values that will change over the lifecycle of a component should be stored in the state of the component, changing the state will cause the component to rerender and thus display the changes on the DOM if the state is utilized correctly. Here is a simple example where each component has a button that triggers the active state to toggle thus triggering a rerender of the component which causes the classes variable to be recomputed therefore changing the class names passed to the div element. I have made the assumption each element is initially false.

```
import React , {useState} from 'react';

const RandComponent = (props) => {
    const [isActive , setIsActive] = useState(false);
    const classes = isActive ? 'bar barActive' : 'bar'; 

    return(
        <>
            <div className={classes}>hi</div>
            <button onClick={() => setIsActive(!isActive)}>{isActive ? 'make me inactive' : 'make me active'}</button>
        </>
    );
}
```